# Mac OS X doesn't recognize hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, dual-boot

I replaced my CD drive with a Western Digital 750GB hard drive using the iFixit guide.

My Mac for some reason throws error on any interaction with the hard drive,
for example on disk utility when I tried to create 1 partition of FAT:

[image: disk utility failure on 1 partition]

When I try to setup BootCamp I get this error:

[image: bootcamp error]

I have successfully managed to erase and format the hard drive while booting up to GParted, but I want to install windows on it.

Do you have any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: Since you formatted it with GParted have you tried installing Windows to that drive while booting the Mac from the Windows installation media?

Comment: I tried, but I checked 3 installation media and they all stuck at the phase of "Windows is loading files..", so I am trying to do this using bootcamp.

Comment: If there is nothing else on the HDD then you shouldn't need to use Boot Camp Assistant for other then to create the USB installation media and download the Windows Support Software, although that can be downloaded separately directly from Apple.  In the past, although not lately, I've install Windows without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant in any capacity.  How was the USB installer created and from what source disc or ISO image? Since Disk Utility had an issue it's not a good sign even though GParted worked.  You may need to resolve that issue first and before installing Windows.

Comment: From ISO using Rufus.

Comment: Did you verify the checksum for the ISO Image and from where was it acquired?

Comment: Yes, I verified it right now.

Comment: What is your HDD speed and what is your HDD controller speed? Some older macs can have problems with SATA3 disks connected to the superdrive sata controller. See for example: http://blog.macsales.com/10433-macbook-pro-2011-models-and-sata-3-0-6-0gbs-update-5272011

Comment: My HDD Controller link speed is 6 Gigabit and as western digital says - http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=790#Tab3 the hard disk is also 6 GBps (my model is WD7500BPKX)

Comment: What's the version of your macbook (e.g. MacBookPro8,2)? You can find this information under system information: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203001

Comment: MacbookPro8,1 (I have upgraded firmware and SMC)

Comment: In that case, like I said, your laptop might not be supporting the 6 GBps, even though techincally it should: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DDMBS6X120/  (look for: "Special compatibility notes related to use of this product with 6Gb/s SSDs in the following machines:"). I had the same issue with my MacBook. 6 GBps is working in the main bay, but not in the optical bay.

Comment: Vincent, http://i.imgur.com/9oU2InD.png It looks like the chipset support 6 gbps.

Comment: Maybe the bay you use for your HDD is the problem. I have experienced numerous troubles with SSDs and bad SATA cables. Now that you have formatted your drive using gParted, does it still face issues in disk utility? If yes, then you're probably facing hardware issues, either with a bay, the cable, or the HDD (likelihood in that order).

Comment: I still have issues with disk utility - if this an hardware issue, how I installed ubuntu on this drive and booted into it? (btw - how can I diagnose which hardware issue is it?)

Comment: Which version of OS X were you running when you tried to use the Disk Utility?

Comment: I used OSX 10.10.3

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue as well. I originally suspected a damaged SATA cable, but swapping the SSD into the optical drive bay and the HD into the primary hard drive bay solved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi Chris, if this an hardware problem - how I managed to install ubuntu on it and it works fine?

Comment: I don't have evidence for this, but one possible explanation is that the SATA cable in the primary bay supports 6 GBps or other advanced communication features, while damage to the cable (or other difference) in the optical bay prevents these features from working there. Maybe Ubuntu can work around the lack of these advanced features, but OS X cannot. This is of course all conjecture.

Comment: I agree with @Chris. The optical drive in my 2011 iMac has a transfer rate of 1.5G bps. There is a good chance the cable is also rated for just that speed. If I was to replace the optical drive with a drive rated at 6G bps, then I would expect hardware problems using the same cable. My guess is your Mac has a cable rated only for a 1.5G bps transfer rate.

Comment: How can I verify that my cable is a 1.5gbps transfer rate? and from where I can buy new cable that supports 6gbps?

Comment: BTW - will this fix the problem for me? https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Early-2011-Late-2011-Hard-Drive-Cable/IF163-026-1

Comment: @Yosi No, that's the hard drive SATA cable which probably works.

Comment: @Yosi AFAIK, I thought the optical bay bus was 3 Gb/s throughput. Either way, it’s a SATA bus and thus should be backward compatible with a SATA III cable. Check the link speed in System Report > Hardware >

Comment: @njboot - The link speed is 6gbps (http://i.imgur.com/9oU2InD.png)

Comment: @klanomath - Why not? as David and Chris said the problem is my sata cable.

Comment: @Yosi If I understand all this correctly (it's getting a bit confusing with the >20 comments here) the hard drive bay & SATA cable works correctly and the SuperDrive bay & SATA cable and attached WD drive doesn't work properly. The cable you proposed is the hard drive bay cable.

Comment: @klanomath - when you say "hard drive bay" you mean the ssd bay? If the sata cable works, what do you think is the problem?

Comment: @Yosi Yeah with hard drive bay I mean the non-superdrive bay! The hard drive bay SATA cable (the long one with the IR-sensor) is very fragile though. I had to replace it 1 month ago in a customer's MacBook Pro. I would suggest a cross check first. SSD->Superdrive bay & HDD->hard drive bay. Then HDD->Superdrive bay & SSD->hard drive bay. If both drives work in the hdd bay it's with high probability NOT the hard drive bay SATA-cable. You may have to boot to Internet Recovery Mode! Did you install any WD software previously (like WD Drive Utilities, WD Security or WD+Turbo) or other disk utils?

Comment: Hi I haven't installed any WD software or other disk utils.
I will try the swapping.

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance it is not a hardware problem with the cable, try creating GUID partitioned disk (GPT) with no partitions. This can not be done using the Disk Utility alone. To do so, follow these instructions.

Open the Disk Utility. Highlight the disk and click on the Info button. Determine the Disk Identifier. In the example below, I used `disk2`.

Close the Disk Utility and open a Terminal window. Enter the following commands. If prompted for a password, enter your login password.

```
diskutil  unmountDisk  /dev/disk2
sudo  dd  if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/disk2  count=40
sudo  gpt  destroy  /dev/disk2
sudo  gpt  create  /dev/disk2
```

Show below are my results.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 count=40
40+0 records in
40+0 records out
20480 bytes transferred in 0.021348 secs (959340 bytes/sec)
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo gpt destroy /dev/disk2
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ sudo gpt create /dev/disk2
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$
```

If everything went well, open the Disk Utility and try to create and format a partition.

If successful, let me know if you need help installing Windows on this computer.

Comment: Hi, The gpt destroy didn't worked (gpt destroy: /dev/disk2: error: device doesn't contain a GPT), the format throw the same error "probing failed".

Comment: Do you have another Mac available? If so try booting your Mac in target disk mode and connect it to another Mac. Try using the Disk Utility on the other Mac. This will eliminate the possibility the problem is with your OS X software.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do things a little differently and this involves separating the problem into two distinct parts - OS and Hardware.

Let's look at hardware first.  I like to use Ultimate Boot CD as it has a number of great utilities to test out your Mac.  It runs on Linux so it completely eliminates OS X from the equation.  And if you are wondering, yes, this will boot and work on your Mac.  I have been doing it on Macs going back to 2006.

First, download, burn, and boot [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com).  There are a number of HDD utilities you can run that will test out your drive for you.

There is a [USB Flash Boot Drive](http://wiki.ultimatebootcd.com/?title=Tutorials:USB_Installation) option instead of a CD (I personally use this).

Boot your machine by holding down the "Option" key before you hear the boot chime.  You will then be able to choose your boot device.

There are a number of HDD tests you can run.  Pick a simple test and run it.

Next, ff everything passes, try using a utility to delete/create a partition

If all works here, then you can attempt to create the bootcamp partition again.

Let us know what happens.